# String filtering in php with preg_match and regular expression

Tags: php, preg-match

I am creating a simple checker function in PHP to validate strings before putting them into an SQL query. But I can not get the right results the from the preg_match function.

```
$myval = "srg845s4hs64f849v8s4b9s4vs4v165";
$tv = preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/', $myval);
echo $tv;
```

Sometimes nothing echoed to the source code, not even a false value... I want to get 1 as the result of this call, because $myval only contains lowercase alphanumerics and numbers.
So is there any way in php to detect if a **string only contains lowercase alphanumerics and numbers** using the preg_match function?

Comment: your code is working properly http://codepad.viper-7.com/sR8SQO

Comment: $myval has a longer length (108 character), but it is also a hash. The above value is just a sample. Is the length the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the circumflex goes outside the [] to indicate the start of the string, you probably need an asterisk to allow an arbitrary number of characters, and you probably want a $ at the end to indicate the end of the string:

```
$tv = preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]*$/', $myval);
```

If you write [^a-z] it means anything else than a-z.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if a string contains lowercase alphanumerics only, I would present your code that way to get the proper results (what you wrote already works):

```
$myval = "srg845s4hs64f849v8s4b9s4vs4v165";
$tv = preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/', $myval);
if($tv === 0){
    echo "the string only contains lowercase alphanumerics";
}else if($tv === 1){
    echo "the string does not only contain lowercase alphanumerics";
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```